# View Flipper that uses Only One ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, viewflipper

I'm new to Android, and am currently using a ViewFlipper. I'd like to know if it's possible to use only one ImageView? That way I can just create an Arraylist of my images. I think using multiple ImageViews is not a good practice since I have 50+ images.

```
public void initContent() {

    imageArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig2);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig3);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig4);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig5);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig6);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig7);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig8);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig9);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig10);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig11);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig12);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig13);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig14);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig24);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.pig25);
    imageArrayList.add(R.drawable.theend);
```

Comment: For optimizing the usage of memory, I will suggest to write your custom ImageFlipper as `ViewFlipper` takes `ImageView` as new object and keeps load on memory.

Comment: @JibranKhan Thank you very much, i was thinking that too. can you give me some links or tuts on how to implement a Custom ImageFlipper? Thank you again in advance

Comment: use my below code it work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    Button Next;
    private Integer images[] = {R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_no_image, R.drawable.calendar52};
    ImageView imageView1;
    private int currImage = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);

        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                currImage++;
                if (currImage == 3) {
                    currImage = 0;
                }
                final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[currImage]);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#4B0082" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                </RelativeLayout>

      </ViewFlipper>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="Next" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the frame animation, delete your arraylist. Here is some sample code: [Link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-quick-tip-creating-frame-animations--mobile-15044)